# Halt spring boot application startup until spring cloud config server is up

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-config

I am trying to run my spring boot application with following properties set and I am expecting it to keep retrying to load properties from config server for 50 times with wait of 6 seconds between any two attempts and even after that it cannot connect to config server, it should either resume the startup or exit (I am indifferent on whatever spring boot is capable of doing after retries). But it doesn't seem like its behaving as expected.

My startup command -

```
java -jar -Dspring.application.name=maas-gateway -Dspring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888 -Dspring.cloud.config.failFast=false -Dspring.cloud.config.retry.initialInterval=5000 -Dspring.cloud.config.retry.maxInterval=7000 -Dspring.cloud.config.retry.maxAttempts=50 maas-gateway-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

But I am getting following errors, as it resumes the startup after one try.

```
    2017-10-06 09:55:05.881  INFO [] 3598 --- [                main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@53e25b76: startup date [Fri Oct 06 09:55:05 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    2017-10-06 09:55:06.136  INFO [] 3598 --- [                main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
    2017-10-06 09:55:06.166  INFO [] 3598 --- [                main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bbc9d7cf] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
      __  __              _____        _____       _
     |  \/  |            / ____|      / ____|     | |
     | \  / | __ _  __ _| (___ ______| |  __  __ _| |_ _____      ____ _ _   _
     | |\/| |/ _` |/ _` |\___ \______| | |_ |/ _` | __/ _ \ \ /\ / / _` | | | |
     | |  | | (_| | (_| |____) |     | |__| | (_| | ||  __/\ V  V / (_| | |_| |
     |_|  |_|\__,_|\__,_|_____/       \_____|\__,_|\__\___| \_/\_/ \__,_|\__, |
                                                                          __/ |
                                                                         |___/
    2017-10-06 09:55:06.494  INFO [] 3598 --- [                main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at: http://localhost:8888
    2017-10-06 09:55:06.579  WARN [] 3598 --- [                main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/maas-gateway/default": Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    2017-10-06 09:55:06.580  INFO [] 3598 --- [                main] com.solace.maas.Application              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
    2017-10-06 09:55:06.601  INFO [] 3598 --- [                main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2ed94a8b: startup date [Fri Oct 06 09:55:06 EDT 2017]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@53e25b76
    2017-10-06 09:55:08.889  INFO [] 3598 --- [                main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'getManagerExecutorService' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=gatewayServiceConfiguration; factoryMethodName=getManagerExecutorService; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/solace/maas/gateway/configuration/GatewayServiceConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=iamServiceConfiguration; factoryMethodName=getManagerExecutorService; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/solace/maas/iam/configuration/IamServiceConfiguration.class]]
    2017-10-06 09:55:08.890  INFO [] 3598 --- [                main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'getMaasProperties' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=gatewayServiceConfiguration; factoryMethodName=getMaasProperties; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/solace/maas/gateway/configuration/GatewayServiceConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=iamServiceConfiguration; factoryMethodName=getMaasProperties; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/solace/maas/iam/configuration/IamServiceConfiguration.class]]
    2017-10-06 09:55:08.898  INFO [] 3598 --- [                main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'getManagerExecutorService' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=iamServiceConfiguration; factoryMethodName=getManagerExecutorService; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/solace/maas/iam/configuration/IamServiceConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=signupManagerConfiguration; factoryMethodName=getManagerExecutorService; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/solace/maas/signupManager/configuration/SignupManagerConfiguration.class]]
    2017-10-06 09:55:09.126  INFO [] 3598 --- [                main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'managementServletContext' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcHypermediaManagementContextConfiguration; factoryMethodName=managementServletContext; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcHypermediaManagementContextConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=managementServletContext; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]]
    2017-10-06 09:55:09.750  WARN [] 3598 --- [                main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'refreshScope' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
    2017-10-06 09:55:09.992  INFO [] 3598 --- [                main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=27bcc9d7-c3a9-3801-b696-3f3650ee7946
    2017-10-06 09:55:10.038  INFO [] 3598 --- [                main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
    2017-10-06 09:55:10.137  INFO [] 3598 --- [                main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.AsyncDefaultAutoConfiguration$DefaultAsyncConfigurerSupport' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.AsyncDefaultAutoConfiguration$DefaultAsyncConfigurerSupport$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dcf17295] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2017-10-06 09:55:10.237  INFO [] 3598 --- [                main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9fafd4d2] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2017-10-06 09:55:10.467  INFO [] 3598 --- [                main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$385d9d0c] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2017-10-06 09:55:10.486  INFO [] 3598 --- [                main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'objectPostProcessor' of type [class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2017-10-06 09:55:10.494  INFO [] 3598 --- [                main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@736d6a5c' of type [class org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2017-10-06 09:55:10.506  INFO [] 3598 --- [                main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5d323fbe] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2017-10-06 09:55:10.571  INFO [] 3598 --- [                main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [class org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2017-10-06 09:55:10.606  INFO [] 3598 --- [                main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.metrics.MetricsInterceptorConfiguration$MetricsRestTemplateConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.metrics.MetricsInterceptorConfiguration$MetricsRestTemplateConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d1dc7b13] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2017-10-06 09:55:10.659  INFO [] 3598 --- [                main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bbc9d7cf] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2017-10-06 09:55:11.342  INFO [] 3598 --- [                main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
    2017-10-06 09:55:11.353  INFO [] 3598 --- [                main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
    2017-10-06 09:55:11.354  INFO [] 3598 --- [                main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.6
    2017-10-06 09:55:11.429  INFO [] 3598 --- [ocalhost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
    2017-10-06 09:55:11.429  INFO [] 3598 --- [ocalhost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4828 ms
    2017-10-06 09:55:12.903 ERROR [] 3598 --- [ocalhost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter    : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'iamServiceConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 3; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3067f332]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonHttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter]: Factory method 'jacksonHttpMessageConverter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'config' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]: Factory method 'config' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userAttributeDAO': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#60b53b0c' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#60b53b0c': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    2017-10-06 09:55:12.932  WARN [] 3598 --- [                main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    2017-10-06 09:55:12.940 ERROR [] 3598 --- [                main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
```

**Description**:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

**Action**:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).

Comment: Can you show the build file?

Comment: Do you have spring-retry as a dependency?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: @spencergibb Thanks for the tip. I was missing spring-retry as a dependency. After putting that, I am getting the desired behaviour.

Comment: Added as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `spring-retry` as a dependency.